# AngularJS - $scope variable is not binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm working on a form in which the user enters his zip code (Brazilian zip code), and clicks on a button that automatically refreshs the inputs with all his address info.
I've done a button so the user could see his address in Google Maps, but the two way data-binding seems not to work.

This is the variable that configs the url of google maps:

```
this.$scope.url = this.$scope.entity.address.logradouro + ' ' +
                    this.$scope.entity.address.numero + ' ' + this.$scope.entity.address.localidade + ' ' + this.$scope.entity.address.uf;
```

And here is the data-binding in the page:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/{{url}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary">GOOGLE MAPS <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></a>
```

When I click, the address on google maps url is:

> https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/null%20null%20null%20null

How do I solve this? Thanks!

P.S. All the other data-bindings are working.

Comment: Are you using the correct names ? Did you imports the JS ?

Comment: I assume that you have to use 'ng-href'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.$scope` with `$scope`.